# Use row reduction to show that the determinant is equal to this variable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Show
determinant of:
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\end{pmatrix}

is equal to $(b - a)(c - a)(c - b)$

I'm not sure if you can use squares or square roots hmmm.. please help me. I'm sure it's a simple question. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see immmediatley that the determinant is a polynomial in $a,b,c$, homgenous of degree $3$. And if $a=b$ or $b=c$ or $c=a$, two columns are identical and make the determiniant zero.
On the other hand, if $a,b,c$ are pairwise distinct, the determinant must be nonzero as any vanishing linear combination of rows would result in a quadratic polynomial having three roots $a,b,c$.
If these arguments are not convincing enough, just employ Gauss's algorithm:
$$\begin{align}\det\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\a^2&b^2&c^2\end{pmatrix} 
&=\det\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&b-a&c-a\\0&b^2-a^2&c^2-a^2\end{pmatrix}\\ 
&=\det\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&b-a&c-a\\0&0&c^2-a^2-(b+a)(c-a)\end{pmatrix}\\
&=(b-a)\cdot(c^2-a^2-(b+a)(c-a))\\
&=(b-a)(c-a)(c+a-(b+a))\\&=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b) \end{align}
$$

Comment: (+1) I beg your pardon, I just gave about the same answer of yours, I bet we were typing it at almost the same time :)

Comment: thanks! :) ur answers was awesome too but a bit complicated. i like the fact that the transpose is useful though @Jack

Answer (score 3):

Subtracting $\DeclareMathOperator{Col}{Col}\Col_1$ from $\Col_2$ and $\Col_3$ gives
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
a & b-a & c-a \\
a^2 & b^2-a^2 & c^2-a^2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
a & b-a & c-a \\
a^2 & (b+a)(b-a) & (c+a)(c-a)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The determinant is then
\begin{align*}
(b-a)(c+a)(c-a)-(c-a)(b+a)(b-a)
&=(b-a)(c-a)(c+a-b-a) \\
&=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)
\end{align*}
Of course, if you'd rather use row operations then you could consider the transpose and use the fact that $\det(A^\top)=\det(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant of such a matrix is a third-degree homogeneous polynomial in $a,b,c$ that vanishes when $a=b,a=c$ or $b=c$, hence:
$$ \det M = K (b-a)(c-a)(c-b) $$
for some constant $K$. To find the value of such a constant, it is sufficient to compute the determinant of $V$ for $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just expand over the first row. Call your matrix A.

|A| = $1(bc^2-cb^2) - 1(ac^2-ca^2) + 1(ab^2-ba^2)$

Show that it is equivalent to (b-a) etc.